# What does the double colon mean in Scope Local variables in Chrome's debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

See the screen dump fragment below.
Notice that there are two colons between legend and Object (legend is a field of ptd). What does the double colon mean?

My problem is that if I test the value of ptd.legend, it is 'undefined'. Which it shouldn't be...

[image: Scope Local]

Comment: Try ptd['legend:'] to get it. It just mean the field is named 'legend:'.

Comment: Have u tried to get the value of `ptd['legend:']`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the property name is actually the string "legend:". You can tell by the syntax highlighting.

For example:

```
obj['legend:'] = 'value';
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the syntax highlighting. The first colon is purple, the second one isn't                                                        :-)